# Multipart Request to Singlepart and Back

Tags: multipartform-data, dataweave, mulesoft

I'm receiving a multipart request similar to:

```
----------------------------778704367722595657997650
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"
Content-Type: application/json

[
    {    
        "subject": "test
    }
]
----------------------------778704367722595657997650
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="logo.jpeg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

jpegdata
----------------------------778704367722595657997650
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="icon.png"
Content-Type: image/png

pngdata
----------------------------778704367722595657997650--
```

Since I'm sending this payload to an SQS queue, I need to transform the payload to JSON for the AWS connector to accept, similar to the following payload, notice the `body` key:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
{
    delaySeconds: 120,
    body: write(payload, 'application/json'),
    messageAttributes: {
        "objectType": {
            "stringValue": "cases",
            "dataType": "String"
        } as Object {
            class: "org.mule.extension.sqs.api.model.MessageAttributeValue"
        }
    } as Object {
        class: "java.util.HashMap"
    }
} as Object {
    class: "org.mule.extension.sqs.api.model.Message"
}
```

The issue I'm running into is that converting the payload to JSON changes the multipart data. For example it converts the image/jpeg to JSON which doesn't deserialize correctly.

I need to pull each `file` out of the request anyway, so I'm rebuilding the multipart request in the downstream application.

Is the correct solution to base64 encode the multipart data and then decode it when I reconstruct the multipart request? Essentially preserving the underlying data?

Answer (score 0):

To process the components of the message later I would recommend no. That would require additional conversions to/from multipart which don't make sense to repeat and would add confusion to the code. Instead use DataWeave to extract the information into an object and store that object in a format that make processing later simpler. For example DataWeave will by default convert a multipart input into an object with the parts. You will need to convert each file to its base64 representation to avoid corruption of binaries when storing in JSON. You could use each part content-type to decide if encode them.